# How to rename a column in pandas dataframe using apply function?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to rename one column in pandas dataframe. I want to do that by using apply function. I wrote a code that does that but I do not know how to use apply fucntion to do this . Can anybody help?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/master/all/all.csv'
df_github = pd.read_csv(url)

df_github  = df_github.rename(columns={'name':'Country'})
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason to use `apply` function, when you have already done it using `rename` function??

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why reinvent the wheel here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with jezrael, this just makes it unnecessarily complicated. That's how I would do it as a 'quick and dirty' solution in case you really want to use `apply` (obviously very similar to jezrael's solution):

`df_github.columns = df_github.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: 'Country' if x == 'name' else x )`

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but overcomplicated, because need convert index to series and then call `lambda` function with `apply`:

```
d = {'name':'Country'}
df_github.columns  = df_github.columns.to_series().apply(lambda x: d.get(x, x))
```